# Undefined reference to static constexpr member only used by value

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-members

I was trying to create a clever class containing a font style. Before this consisted of 3 enums with bit-wise compatible values (each set of values did not had overlapping bits with the other enums) so you could do `FontStyle::LEFT | FontStyle::TOP`

But clang warned me about combining unrelated enums and yes I've seen possible bugs here: `FontStyle::LEFT | FontStyle::RIGHT` did set both bits. So I reworked the class using a helper class for the former enums and templates to match correct values. But now I'm getting linker errors for clang on Debug builds about `undefined reference` to my `static constexpr` members.

Looking at [Undefined reference error for static constexpr member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690260/undefined-reference-error-for-static-constexpr-member) suggests, that the value is ODR-used, but I'm not using any references.

[When does a static constexpr class member need an out-of-class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077703/when-does-a-static-constexpr-class-member-need-an-out-of-class-definition) this then pointed me to the implicit copy constructor of my helper class which is the issue.

Is there any chance I can avoid the out-of-class definitions in C++14 (C++17 already allows to omit them) and Debug builds (Ctors are optimized away in Release and hence no undefined references)?

[Related code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jy7NRi59ukfiGHjV):

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

namespace detail {
template<unsigned T_index>
struct FontStylePart
{
    constexpr FontStylePart(uint8_t val) : value(val) {}
    uint8_t value;
};
} // namespace detail

class FontStyle
{
    static constexpr unsigned AlignH = 0;
    static constexpr unsigned AlignV = 1;

public:
    constexpr FontStyle() = default;

    template<unsigned T_index>
    constexpr FontStyle(detail::FontStylePart<T_index> style) : FontStyle()
    {
        value[T_index] = style.value;
    }

    /// Horizontal align
    static constexpr detail::FontStylePart<AlignH> LEFT = 0;
    static constexpr detail::FontStylePart<AlignH> RIGHT = 1;
    static constexpr detail::FontStylePart<AlignH> CENTER = 2;

    /// Vertical align
    static constexpr detail::FontStylePart<AlignV> TOP = 0;
    static constexpr detail::FontStylePart<AlignV> BOTTOM = 1;
    static constexpr detail::FontStylePart<AlignV> VCENTER = 2;

private:

    std::array<uint8_t, 3> value = {{0, 0, 0}};
};

int main() {
  FontStyle style = FontStyle::CENTER;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any subclass in the code, so it is not clear where exactly ODR use is happening. Can you isolate the problem in MCVE?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped at one place. I meant the helper class not subclass. The MCVE is posted above with link to wandbox which shows the linker error

Comment: I think that this code should work (should not odr-use `FontStyle::CENTER`). Indeed it builds and runs when I change the compiler to clang 8.0.0

Comment: @Brian Unfortunately no. Did you set the C++ standard to C++14? In C++14 this does not work for the aforementioned reasons while in C++17 and up it does.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
FontStyle style = FontStyle::CENTER;
```

is a ODR use of `FontStyle::CENTER`.

I tried using

```
constexpr FontStyle style = FontStyle::CENTER;
```

but I ran into problems in the constructor. The following works although it's not clear to me whether that is acceptable for your needs.

```
int main() {
   constexpr auto v = FontStyle::CENTER;
   FontStyle style = v;
   return 0;
}
```

This transfers the onus of ODR use to `constexpr auto v`.

Comment: Only because the CopyConstructor of FontStylePart is invoked. How can I avoid this?

Comment: C++17 allows elision of constructor.